# Find the $102^{\text{nd}}$ derivative of a function at $x=0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am required to find the $102^{\text{nd}}$ derivative of $f(x) = e^{2x^3}$ at $x=0$.

I have seen that for the Taylor series of $e^x$ we can get: $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$
Therefore, for $e^{2x^3}$ we would have:
$$e^{2x^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{2^n}{x^{3n}}}{n!}$$

But now I am a bit stuck.
It seems that I should now say that $3n=102$ which gives $n=34$, but I do not completely understand why I need to divide by $3$.
Can someone please assist me with this situation or provide some references where I can get more infomation?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Using Taylor expansion of a function we can write
$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0) x^k}{k!}$$

So The coefficient of $x^k$ is $\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} $. In your case $k =3n=102$. So $f^{(3n)}(0)/(3n)! = 2^n /n!$.

So you need the value of $n$ when you know $3n$

Answer (score 0):

You divide by $3$ to find the value of $n$ for the non-vanishing term after differentiating $102$ times and setting $x=0$, which occurs when $n=34.$

We have

$$f(x)=e^{2x^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{2^n}{x^{3n}}}{n!}=1+\frac{2^{1}}{1!}x^{3}+\frac{2^2}{2!}x^{6}+...+\frac{2^n}{n!}x^{3n}+...$$

For which $n$ do we obtain the term involving $x^{102}$?

Differentiating we obtain

$$f'(x)=\frac{2^1}{1!}\cdot3x^2+\frac{2^2}{2!}\cdot6x^5+...$$

$$f''(x)=\frac{2^1}{1!}\cdot3\cdot 2x+\frac{2^2}{2!}\cdot6\cdot 5 x^4+...$$

$$f'''(x)=\frac{2^1}{1!}\cdot3\cdot 2+\frac{2^2}{2!}\cdot6\cdot 5 \cdot 4x^3+...=\frac{2^{1}}{1!}\cdot3!+\frac{2^2}{2!}\cdot6\cdot 5 \cdot 4x^3+...$$

So setting $x=0$ gives $f'''(0)=12,$ which is the third derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$.

What term will remain when you differentiate $102$ times and set $x=0$?